# How to get current time in hh:mm:ss format using moment in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, momentjs

I want to calculate the time between hours and moments. with example:

```
export const DataCoba: React.FC = () => {
const format = "hh:mm:ss";
  return (
    <div>
      {moment(format).isBetween(
        moment("21:00:00", format),
        moment("23:00:00", format)
      )
        ? "Between"
        : "NOOO"}
    </div>
  );
};
```

from the script above what I want is to get the current time, but only in hh:mm:ss format only.
for example: `moment('23:00:00', hh:mm:ss)`.

moment(format) is showing invalid date. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Have you added a dependency for moment in your package.json? Have you imported it into this source file?

Comment: Your script is not getting the current time, it is a boolean function that returns true if the curr time is between the two times you wrote. Also, moment does not take format as a first parameter.

Comment: Does the Format really matter here? You could simply do `moment().isBetween(moment().set('hour', 21), moment().set('hour', 23)) ? 'Yes' : 'No'`. Moment is a DateTime library; you're trying to use it with Time only.

Comment: @KevinHooke yes I have imported it

Comment: @TimLewis can I set time with hour and minutes? for example I have a time range of 21:00 to 23:30, Sir?

Comment: Yes, `.set('minute', 0)` or whatever value you'd like.

Comment: Don't edit the word "solved" into the title of your question. Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Note that Moment is [not recommended](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/).

Comment: @Quentin the solution is in the comments. So there is no answer to accept in that way. Though I do agree adding "Solved" to the title is not correct.

Comment: Then the commenter could be encourage to convert their comment to an answer, the OP could community wiki a self-answer, or the question could be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my expected answer from @TimLewis

```
moment().isBetween(moment().set('hour', 21), moment().set('hour', 23)) ? 'Yes' : 'No'
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete your first moment's parameter. Because actually your second and third moment is have the same day as your first moment.

Try this one:

```
export const DataCoba: React.FC = () => {
const format = "hh:mm:ss";
  return (
    <div>
      {moment().isBetween(
        moment("21:00:00", format),
        moment("23:00:00", format)
      )
        ? "Between"
        : "NOOO"}
    </div>
  );
};
```